# SUMIFS with dates returning 0 for values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula that sums the Quantities (Column C) when it matches the Account Number (Column B) between Dates (Column A).  My formula is `=SUMIFS(C2:C29407,B2:B29407, E2, A2:A29407,"=>"& H2,A2:A29407,"<=" & H3)`  where E2 is the account number and H2 is the start date and H3 is the end date.  I checked that column A's cell format is date as well as H2 and H3.  Column C is set as number.  Column B does have account numbers that are numbers and some that are letters though.

When I do `=SUMIF(B:B,E2,C:C)` it works and when I do `=SUMIF(A:A,"<="&H3,C:C)` or `=SUMIF(A:A,"=>"&H2,C:C)` it works.  But when I add all 3 of those up into a SUMIFS, it results in 0.  I attached images below to show.  I am lost, please help!
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your Excel version?

Comment: Office 365 - Excel Version 1902

Comment: Typo: `=>` should be  `>=`

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you soooo much!!

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be like below :

For **Less Than Equal to** : `=SUMIF(A:A,"<="&H3,C:C)`

For **Greater Than Equal to** : `=SUMIF(A:A,">="&H2,C:C)`

Your formula is correct for **Less Than Equal to**, but the issue is in **Greater Than equal to** symbol it should be `">="` instead of `"=>"`.